# Duplicated Cassandra SSTable files

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

After unsuccessful `nodetool repair` operation I got two big sstable files (last two in the listing below) instead of one, each having the same size as a single file before. And now this files cannot be merged back by common tools (nodetool clean, nodetool compact, nodetool repair). Tables are replicated to another cassandra node (replication_factor: 2), and there are two big sstable files as well now.

````
-rw-r--r--   1 cassandra cassandra  16M Mar  5 12:36 mc-116413-big-Data.db
-rw-r--r--   1 cassandra cassandra  34M Mar  5 01:21 mc-116320-big-Index.db
-rw-r--r--   1 cassandra cassandra  39M Mar  3 22:46 mc-116125-big-Index.db
-rw-r--r--   1 cassandra cassandra  66M Mar  5 12:25 mc-116412-big-Data.db
-rw-r--r--   1 cassandra cassandra 262M Mar  5 05:51 mc-116365-big-Data.db
-rw-r--r--   1 cassandra cassandra 263M Mar  5 08:46 mc-116386-big-Data.db
-rw-r--r--   1 cassandra cassandra 263M Mar  5 11:42 mc-116407-big-Data.db
-rw-r--r--   1 cassandra cassandra 7.2G Mar  5 03:18 mc-116345-big-Data.db
-rw-r--r--   1 cassandra cassandra  43G Mar  3 22:46 mc-116125-big-Data.db
-rw-r--r--   1 cassandra cassandra  48G Mar  5 01:21 mc-116320-big-Data.db```

I suppose that one of this files contains duplicated data. How can I compact files back to a single file?
````

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm not looking properly but I don't see any duplicate SSTable files in the file listing you posted.

If you're referring to these 2:

```
-rw-r--r--   1 cassandra cassandra  43G Mar  3 22:46 mc-116125-big-Data.db
-rw-r--r--   1 cassandra cassandra  48G Mar  5 01:21 mc-116320-big-Data.db
```

They're not duplicates because they have 2 different generation IDs -- `116125` and `116320`. This means they also have different ancestors.

If you're referring to these:

```
-rw-r--r--   1 cassandra cassandra  39M Mar  3 22:46 mc-116125-big-Index.db
-rw-r--r--   1 cassandra cassandra  43G Mar  3 22:46 mc-116125-big-Data.db

-rw-r--r--   1 cassandra cassandra  34M Mar  5 01:21 mc-116320-big-Index.db
-rw-r--r--   1 cassandra cassandra  48G Mar  5 01:21 mc-116320-big-Data.db
```

Again, they're not duplicates of each other. The `*-Data.db` files contain the actual data. The `*-Index.db` files are component files which contain the partition index, i.e. the index of the partitions within the data files which are used for fast retrieval.

If you're interested, I've explained it in a bit more detail in this post -- https://community.datastax.com/questions/5219/. Cheers!

**[UPDATE]** To respond to this follow-up question:

> *Could you suppose why this two files don`t compacted in a single file,*
> *as usual do?*

Assuming the table is configured with `SizeTieredCompactionStrategy`, it will require similar-sized sstables as candidates before they get compacted together.

The [default minimum sstable candidates](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql-oss/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cqlCreateTable.html#compactSubprop__compactionSubpropertiesSTCS) is `min_threshold: 4` so you need 4 similarly-sized sstables for a compaction to be triggered.

Comment: Hi Erick  
Saying 'duplicate` I don\`t mean 'exactly equal'. I just suppose that data within one file may duplicate data within another one, because before that failed repair the total size of the whole tables was about 50Gb,
Could you suppose why this two files don`t compacted in a single file, as usual do?

Comment: Let me update my answer to respond to your follow up question as I may run out of space here. :) Cheers!

Comment: Erick, you are right, I use STCS. New sstable files grow up to 2Gb size before they are compacted, but I suppose this two files are never going to be compacted this way. So, how can fix that? Should I use sstablesplit to split this files into many smaller one, or temporarily change some compaction settings?

Comment: Yes, you can use `sstablesplit` but that's an offline tool meaning you can't run it on live SSTables (i.e. with C* running). The alternative is to manually trigger a compaction. See the details I posted here -- https://community.datastax.com/questions/6385/. Cheers!